# Elements won't center on div

Tags: html, css

Elements won't center on my div, even though I've went through all the possible (or at least so many that I decided to create a Stack Overflow account finally) ways to fix it
They center on PC, but doesn't work for mobile devices. I've defined this in the CSS

```css
.page_content {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(94, 182, 86, 1) 48%, rgba(121, 230, 111, 1) 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body style="color: #efefef">
  <div class="page_content">
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <button class="button" onclick="testFunction()">Example</button>
    <h1>Buttons</h1>
    <button class="button" onclick="testFunction1()">btn 1</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="button" onclick="testFunction2()">btn 2</button>

  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Try and remove `padding: 20px;` or set it to `padding: 20px 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to delete the `padding: 20px;` in the class `.page_content`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this CSS code :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
}
.page_content {
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top, right top,
    color-stop(48%, rgba(94, 182, 86, 1)),
    to(rgba(121, 230, 111, 1))
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(94, 182, 86, 1) 48%,
    rgba(121, 230, 111, 1) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(94, 182, 86, 1) 48%,
    rgba(121, 230, 111, 1) 100%
  );
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  place-content: center;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix your problem.

**Method 1** - Removing padding
The elements are not centered becuase there is some padding givien to `.page-content` in the css.

**Method 2** - Adding box-sizing.
If you need the padding for your div, then you should add `box-sizing` for the parent container. Which, from the code you have given, is the body. This property includes any padding & margin in the container's total width and height.

I have added `box-sizing:boder-box;` to your code below.

```css
body{
box-sizing:border-box; /*ADD THIS*/
}

.page_content {
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(94,182,86,1) 48%, rgba(121,230,111,1) 100%);
   padding: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   justify-content: center;
   top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
   position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body style="color: #efefef">
    <div class="page_content">
      <h1>Home page</h1>
      <button class="button" onclick="testFunction()">Example</button>
      <h1>Buttons</h1>
      <button class="button" onclick="testFunction1()">btn 1</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="button" onclick="testFunction2()">btn 2</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```